# Is there a way to check a specific consistency in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-view

I have these tables in my database:

- Company (**Symbol**, Sector, Founded, Location)
- Stock (**tDate**, Symbol, Price)

Columns in bold are the primary key for each table.

I need to find the companies where for every date in the database (in `tDate`), their stock price has gone up, without using functions.

Is there a possible way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they only have rising prices, then for the same symbol there's no newer stock with a lower price.

> ```
> create table Company (
>  Symbol varchar(30) primary key, 
>  Name varchar(30),
>  Sector int default 0, 
>  Founded date, 
>  Location varchar(30)
> );
>
> create table Stock (
>  tDate date, 
>  Symbol varchar(30), 
>  Price decimal(10,2), 
>  foreign key (Symbol) references Company(Symbol)
> );
>
> insert into Company (Symbol, Name) values
>   ('rise', 'Rising Star Inc.')
> , ('updo', 'Ups & Downs')
>
> insert into Stock (tDate, Symbol, Price) values
>   ('2021-12-01', 'rise', 101.00)
> , ('2021-12-02', 'rise', 102.00)
> , ('2021-12-03', 'rise', 103.00)
> , ('2021-12-04', 'rise', 104.00)
>
> , ('2021-12-01', 'updo', 202.00)
> , ('2021-12-02', 'updo', 201.00)
> , ('2021-12-03', 'updo', 204.00)
> , ('2021-12-04', 'updo', 203.00)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT Symbol
> FROM Company
> WHERE Symbol IN (
>    SELECT Symbol
>    FROM Stock
>    GROUP BY Symbol
>    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
>    EXCEPT
>    SELECT DISTINCT Symbol
>    FROM Stock s1
>    WHERE EXISTS (
>      SELECT 1
>      FROM Stock s2
>      WHERE s2.Symbol = s1.Symbol
>        AND s2.tDate > s1.tDate
>        AND s2.Price < s1.Price
>    )
> );
> ```

| Symbol |
| --- |
| rise |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2f26f4d9a122e542168570f2015c08e2)*